# How to get Count in Hibernate using JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm Using Hibernate with JPA and MySql.

SQL Tabel have `ClassTable`---->`TimeTable`----->`Skillset`----->Course

the above arrow marks are showing `one to many` Relation ship.

Now in my Java code ...

```
public List<ClassTableVO> getClassTables() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from ClassTableVO",
            ClassTableVO.class).getResultList();
}
```

But my requirement is Count the courses, How many in the ClassTable.

For example ClassTabel Have 10 record and 4 records `java` and 6 records `flex` now i want to these count and storing one integer variable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
public int getRecordCount(String subject) {
    return session.createCriteria(ClassTableVO.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("subject", subject)).getResultList()
            .size();
}
```

Comment: No.no we are return List<ClasstabelVO> but just we are store count in ClasstabelVO--class variable.

Comment: This is a separate method. And is not related to your getClassTables() method

Comment: error:Add cast to Receiver method is showing eclipse ide in add()

Comment: i'm only using EntityManager then how we create Session object is their any method in jpa..

Answer (score 1):

Select count(courses) from classtable where courses='java' 
(OR)
Select count(courses) from classtable group by( courses)

Comment: But hear many courses their like java and flex and also courses are depending on Classtabel ..

Comment: but my classtable have timetableid and timetable have skillsetid and skillset have courseid and course have name. so in that time how to capture name.